# Trying to code 99 bottles of beer in python

Tags: python

I'm in an intro to programming using python class and our homework is to do the 99 bottles of beer song. We haven't learned a lot yet so this is really all i can come up with:

```
def StandardVerse():
    print n, "bottles of beer on the wall,", n, ",bottles of beer"
    print "take one down pass it around,",n,"bottles of beer on the wall."

def TwoBottles():
    print "Two bottles of beer on the wall, two bottles of beer."
    print "Take one down pass it around, one bottle of beer on the wall."

def OneBottle():
    print "One bottle of beer on the wall, One bottle of beer."
    print "Take one down, pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall."

def NoBottles():
    print "No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer."
    print "Go to the store, buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall."

for n in range(99,0,-1):
    if n > 2:
        print StandardVerse
    if n == 2:
        print TwoBottles
    if n == 1:
        print OneBottle
    if n <= 1:
        print NoBottles
```

It gives me this when i run it

```
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function StandardVerse at 0x027BEC30>
<function TwoBottles at 0x027BEC70>
<function OneBottle at 0x027BECB0>
<function NoBottles at 0x027BECF0>
```

and so on up to the 99 bottles (I didn't copy it all for the sake of space.)

What can i do to make it print out the actual song?

Comment: If you are going to print the function calls then return the strings or else don't pting just call

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `n` to `StandardVerse`, n can only be equal to one number at a time so use if/elis's and else, don't print your function calls as the return no value so `None` by default which you will see if you print:

```
def StandardVerse(n):
    print n, "bottles of beer on the wall,", n, ",bottles of beer"
    print "take one down pass it around,",n,"bottles of beer on the wall."

def TwoBottles():
    print "Two bottles of beer on the wall, two bottles of beer."
    print "Take one down pass it around, one bottle of beer on the wall."

def OneBottle():
    print "One bottle of beer on the wall, One bottle of beer."
    print "Take one down, pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall."

def NoBottles():
    print "No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer."
    print "Go to the store, buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall."

for n in range(99,0,-1):
    if n > 2:
        StandardVerse(n)
    elif n == 2:
        TwoBottles()
    elif n == 1:
        OneBottle()
    else:
        NoBottles()
```

If `n` is not > 2, equal to 1 or equal to w it must be `0` in the context of your range.

Answer (score 1):

You get `None` in between lines because you're `print`ing the return values of the functions, which don't explicitly return anything (and so, in fact, they return `None`).

Also, you need to pass `n` to `StandardVerse`. This will work:

```
for n in range(99, 0, -1):
    if n > 2:
        StandardVerse(n)
    elif n == 2:
        TwoBottles()
    elif n == 1:
        OneBottle()
    else:               # n == 0
        NoBottles()
```

Answer (score 0):

use StandardVerse() and so on. This way you call the function and the prints will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a need for an additional `print()` call.  Simply calling the function should work:

```
for n in range(99,0,-1):
    if n > 2:
        StandardVerse(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
for i in range(99, -1, -1):
    if i > 2:
        print ('{} bottles of beer on the wall!\n{} bottles of beer!\nTake one down\nAnd pass it around\n{} bottles of beer on the wall!\n\n'.format (i,i,i-1))
    elif i == 2:
        print ('{} bottles of beer on the wall!\n{} bottles of beer!\nTake one down\nAnd pass it around\n1 more bottle of beer on the wall!\n\n'.format (i,i,))
    elif i == 1:
        print ('1 bottle of beer on the wall!\n1 bottle of beer!\nTake it down\nAnd pass it around\nNo more bottles of beer on the wall!')
print()
```

Answer (score -3):

here you go:

```
for n in range(99,0,-1):
    if n > 2:
        StandardVerse()
    if n == 2:
        TwoBottles()
    if n == 1:
        OneBottle()
    if n <= 1:
        NoBottles()
```

Comment: why did i get -1. Test the code before you think that is something wrong with it

Comment: You need to test it too... StandardVerse() is missing the parameter, should be StandardVerse(`n`)

Comment: Technically, `n` is a global and the implementation above should still work (even though `n` should be a parameter to the function).

Comment: i test it before i post it ;) (I always test my code), it works fine.